# Position of a QToolButton does not change when resizing or moving the parent widget

Tags: c++, qt, position, qt4, qtoolbutton

I have a class called Titlebar inherited from QWidget. The following code goes inside the constructor of Titlebar class:

```
m_queueBtn = new QToolButton;
m_serverToolBar = new QToolBar;
m_serverToolBar->addWidget(m_queueBtn);

QPoint pos = m_queueBtn->pos();
```

While printing `m_queueBtn->pos()`, it's always showing the same value instead of the resize or move.

Comment: Do you actually print the position when you resize the parent or just in the constructor once?

Answer (score 2):

The [size-policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo) of a `QToolButton` is a `Fixed/Fixed` by default, so resizing its parent will have no effect. Also, `pos()` returns coordinates that are relative to its parent widget - so again, moving the parent will have no effect.

If you want to get the *global* position of a child widget (i.e. relative to the desktop), you can use [mapToGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal):

```
QPoint pos = m_queueBtn->mapToGlobal(m_queueBtn->pos());
```

Or to translate child coordinates to a position relative to one of its ancestor widgets, you can use [mapTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo):

```
QPoint pos = m_queueBtn->mapTo(ancestor, QPoint(0, 0));
```